# Adding Currency sign to numeric value so that data type will remain as float. python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, currency, finance

I have a dataframe, and I need to add a currency sign to a numeric value in a column, so that the datatype of that column will still remain the same as float type, so i can sum or find mean.

when I add '$' sign to numeric value, all values change their type to string

I tried format, but it convert values to string datatype

Comment: on stackoverflow, it's a best practice to include the code you've tried in the question, and also a sample of your dataframe so we can reproduce the issue. that being said, what you're asking for doesn't sound possible – when you add a non-numeric symbol, your column becomes a string or object type

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please checkout the [tour], [ask] and [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Additionally add the appropriate code in your question as text. See [mre] for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to *store* the value including a dollar sign ($), but rather to prepend or append the dollar sign to the value when you're generating user-facing text.

For instance, you could write code that looks like this:

```py
price = my_function_to_get_a_price()  # price is now a float
print(f"The price is ${price:.2f}")
```

However, it's possible that when dealing with currency you may encounter a variety of floating point errors. It's therefore often best practice to either store amounts of currency as an `int` representing cents (so, $1.37 would be `137`) or use the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) library.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/455634/21297704) from Rex Logan.